# Installing VNC server in raspberry pi

Tags: display, keyboard, vnc

I got my raspberry pi couple of days back and am looking to use my laptop for display, mouse and keyboard, I have heard that, it is possible through installing VNC server in Raspberry pi.

Can anyone please post a complete procedure for doing it and also frequently encountered problems while installing.

Answer (score 2):

To control your *RaspberryPI* through *VNC* using another computer do this:

**Inside the RaspberryPi:**

Install `x11vnc`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

Then, execute `x11vnc` as follow to assign a password that must be used when connecting to your VNC server:

```
$ x11vnc -storepasswd
Enter VNC password: 
Verify password:    
Write password to /home/pi/.vnc/passwd?  [y]/n 
Password written to: /home/pi/.vnc/passwd
```

**Inside your other computer:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
$ x11vnc_ssh pi@192.168.1.57:0
```

Here `192.168.1.57` should be the IP of your *RaspberryPi*. This will ask for a password, which is the same you assigned inside your *RaspberryPi* to the VNC server.

This is the expected result:

[image: Screenshot from RPi + x11vnc]

**Note:** In my case the `x11vnc_ssh` is too verbose, so much that I couldn't see the password prompt from the server. So I chose to "disable" the stderr like this:

```
x11vnc_ssh pi@192.168.1.57:0 2>/dev/null
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Raspbian Pixel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/) came out, it is now recommended to install the official RealVNC server using `sudo apt-get install -y realvnc-vnc-server`. This is much faster and has much better quality that `x11vnc`, because RealVNC is the company that made VNC in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install tightvnc
```

Is probably your best bet.  You'll need to be able to ssh into it, and this assumes you have the debian build also.